# In Java String, How to cut a part of a String by just 1 line of code (probally use Regex)?

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

given this string `http://verylongurlverylonngurl/image.jpg` & I wanna cut all the part before the last "/". For example, I wanna remove the part `http://verylongurlverylonngurl/` of the string above. The result will be "image.jpg".

I have to cut the String "Label" & the code to cut that String must be inside the super() keyword & super keyword must be the first statement in the constructor. Loook at this code:

```
private class TextShortenedCheckBox extends CheckBox{
      private String originalText;
       public TextShortenedCheckBox(String label, int visibleLength){
            super(label.substring(label.length()-9,label.length()-1));


            originalText=label;

       }
       @Override
       public String getText(){
          return originalText;
       }
    }
```

Look at the code: `label.substring(label.length()-9,label.length()-1)` this code give the result but not be able to apply for other variable string.

So, how to cut a part of a String by just 1 line of code, so that I can put that code inside super(). Maybe we have to use Regex or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about

```
str = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Comment: Yes, much better than regex. A small note: you are off by one and will include the leading slash.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Thanks. Wasn't 100% sure and too lazy to actually run the code ;)

Comment: Thax you jlordo, it's simple perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lastIndexOf('/')](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29)

Returns the index within this string of the last occurrence of the specified character. For values of `ch` in the range from `0 to 0xFFFF` (inclusive), the index (in Unicode code units) returned is the largest value `k` such that: `this.charAt(k) == ch` is true. For other values of ch, it is the largest value `k` such that: `this.codePointAt(k) == ch` is true. In either case, if no such character occurs in this string, then `-1` is returned. The String is searched backwards starting at the last character.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String str ="http://verylongurlverylonngurl/image.jpg";
str = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
image.jpg
```